# Which is better: Catching database exception or creating manual check?

Tags: database, exception

I'm using hibernate with MySQL database server. Consider a sample database table:

```
create table User (
    USER_ID int not null auto_increment primary key,
    USERNAME varchar(50) not null unique,
    PASSWORD varchar(50) not null
)
```

With this table structure, it throws org.hibernate.exception.**DataException** and  org.hibernate.exception.**ConstraintViolationException** if an attempt is made to store longer or duplicate username.

Question: what approach is better in such scenarios:

1. Checking database constraints before passing values (preventing an expected exception).
2. Passing unchecked data and catching database exceptions (DataException and ConstraintViolationException) later on.

Since checking name length is a constant time operation, I preferred a manual check on it, but this question becomes important to me since ensuring username uniqueness manually require me to iterate a long list of existing users.

Please suggest which approach is more recommendable. Thanks for replies!

Comment: Checking up front is expensive (extra query) *and* unreliable (another process could have added the user after you checked).  There's not much point in writing expensive unreliable code.

Comment: Just take note that between process #1 and #2 an other user can insert the same username. Checking for #1 might be useless in some case. But now with powerfull UI, I often see error message update live as I write the form. (ex: After writting a username but not submitting, the UI tells me if the name is taken or not).

Comment: So can I conclude that thread safe checks should be implemented manually (like checking username length), and catching exception thrown by DB Server where exact result may depend on parallel threads.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do *both*.

You shouldn't let hibernate exceptions percolate up out of the persistence layer - the user of your code probably has no idea (nor should they ever) that your persistence implementation uses hibernate, so throw a *domain* excpetion - one that fits the API as the caller sees it.

If you can check the validity of input in your code, that's much better than letting the database explode. You can define and throw a domain exception:

```
if (username.length() > 8) {
    throw new BadUsernameException("username is longer than 8 chars");
```

and you could even find if the username has already been used:

```
if (<query database to find username already used>)
    throw new BadUsernameException("username already used");
```

Or you may throw separate Exceptions for each case, but beware of anti-pattern of controlling flow via Exceptions.

---

You still need to catch exceptions due to race conditions, but they will be rare indeed. You may chose to throw a domain exception.

Answer (score 1):

You always have to do 2) anyway.  Your client code cannot enforce many of the things you might want to in any case (primary keys, constraints enforced at commit time etc.).  Only the database can provide proper consistency checking.

So certainly do 2 and do 1 if you don't mind doubling/tripling up on your coding (database, middle and UI) but bear in mind that a client check will always run the risk of being out of date as soon as it's finished.  Not so for the database check.

Answer (score 0):

From user point of view, it's unacceptable to send filled form into DB and it returns an exception only because of too large username. In the time of AJAX.

So, there are three things:

- UI which would check conditions, but UI will probably not verify foreign keys
- your domaind/service should also provide verification. Suppose you have REST server and UI above. You can't be sure that REST is filled only using your correct UI and whether REST client verifies the size - it probably does not
- DB must verify all constraints and it's mostly the only place which can verify all conditions, e.g. in the case of foreign keys.

I believe that middle points is mostly relaxed.

Answer (score 0):

You should do them both. Implementing simple checks before sending a query to the DB might save you time and will make your service more responsive. At the same time catching exceptions would keep your service safe from really unexpected behavior and will make it more user-firendly.

You also mention username uniqueness. If you check in your code whether this name exists you should do a query instead and take action depending on the result - empty or not.